# Convert string to correct date string

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have code that generates xml from database data.

Here is it

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Index(DateTime today)
    {
        var timeTables = db.TimeTables
            .Where(c=> c.Today == today)
            .Select(c => new
            {
                c.INN,
                c.StartDay,
                c.StartPause,
                c.EndPause,
                c.EndDay
            }).AsEnumerable();

        var xdoc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("data",
                timeTables.Select(w =>
                    new XElement("worker",
                        new XAttribute("id", w.INN),
                        new XElement("start", w.StartDay),
                        new XElement("pause", w.StartPause),
                        new XElement("continue", w.EndPause),
                        new XElement("end", w.EndDay)
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        return new HttpResponseMessage() { Content = new StringContent(xdoc.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml") };
    }
```

Data is takes from mobile app request. Mobile app sending  c.StartDay for example like this `17-8-2017T10:8:3`. In xml I need to show it like this `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`

How I can do this on xml generation?

Comment: but `c.StartDay` can also be `17-12-2017T10:45:55` ?=!

Comment: Yes. You are right@MongZhu

Comment: It must be recorded in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` @MongZhu

Comment: is `c.StartDay` a `string` ?

Comment: Yes. It's string@MongZhu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first parse the string you are getting to a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(c.StartDay,"d-M-yyyyTH:m:s", 
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

and then in the xml show it the way you like:

```
.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
```

You can do all of that in one statement during your select:

```
var timeTables = db.TimeTables
        .Where(c=> c.Today == today)
        .Select(c => new
        {
            c.INN,
            StartDay = DateTime.ParseExact(c.StartDay,"d-M-yyyyTH:m:s", 
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                               .ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"),
            c.StartPause,
            c.EndPause,
            c.EndDay
        }).AsEnumerable();
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since linq-to-entities doesn't support these kind of method, you can use it after in the `XmlElement`:

```
new XElement("start", DateTime.ParseExact(w.StartDay,"d-M-yyyyTH:m:s", 
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                              .ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")),
```

Comment: You'll want just a single `s` on your date string to account for single figure seconds.

Comment: Have this `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: Ok, i didn't realize its linq-to-entities. it won't work in the lambda, do it after int the XmlElement, will update the answer

Comment: Thank's for help so much)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 w.StartDay.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
```

or try this:

```
DateTime _latestDepartTime = DateTime.ParseExact(w.StartDay.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

next solution:

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(w.StartDay.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",
                                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Nope, it not helps

Comment: But I cant use in this construction
`var xdoc = new XDocument(
                new XElement("data",
                    timeTables.Select(w =>
                        new XElement("worker",
                            new XAttribute("id", w.INN),
                            new XElement("start", w.StartDay),
                            new XElement("pause", w.StartPause),
                            new XElement("continue", w.EndPause),
                            new XElement("end", w.EndDay)
                        )`

Comment: @mark_spencer try this: var xdoc = new XDocument( new XElement("data", timeTables.Select(w => new XElement("worker", new XAttribute("id", w.INN), new XElement("start", DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(w.StartDay.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",
                                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), new XElement("pause", w.StartPause), new XElement("continue", w.EndPause), new XElement("end", w.EndDay) )

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2017-12-17 10:45:55");
```